# Javascript onchange doesn't triggered

Tags: javascript, radio-button, onchange

On change option, input's value will be changed, but...

```
<input type="radio" name="1_layer" id="1_1" value="">
<select name="1_select" id="1_1" onchange="schange(this.id)">
```

I have no idea why is work just first line:

```
function schange(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked=true;
    var sel = document.getElementByName("1_select");
    var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
    document.getElementByName("1_layer").value == val;
}
```

Comment: What is the extra character 'k" in this line var sel = document.getElementByName("1_select");к?

Comment: == is comparison not assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method `document.getElementByName`, but `document.getElementsByName`. And you should use `=` instead of `==`. So the code is:

```
function schange(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).checked=true;
    var sel = document.getElementsByName("1_select")[0];
    var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementsByName("1_layer")[0].value = val;
}
```